# WPF: how to reload AggregateCatalog in Prism + MEF?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mef

How to properly reload Prism's AggregateCatalog ? When a file changes, I need Prism to reload its catalog, but it keeps giving me this error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.ComponentModel.Composition.ChangeRejectedException' occurred
>   in System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll

Here is the Bootstrapper snippet. It fails when I clear the AggregateCatalog.

```
class Bootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
    private readonly FileSystemWatcher _fileWatcher;

    public Bootstrapper()
    {
        _fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Modules"));
        _fileWatcher.Created += fileWatcher_Changed;
        _fileWatcher.Changed += fileWatcher_Changed;
        _fileWatcher.Deleted += fileWatcher_Changed;
        _fileWatcher.Renamed += fileWatcher_Changed;
        _fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void fileWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Clear(); //It fails here!
        ConfigureAggregateCatalog();
        ConfigureContainer();
    }
```

Comment: What errors are contained in `ChangeRejectedException.Errors` list?

Comment: The composition remains unchanged. The changes were rejected because of the following error(s): The composition produced multiple composition errors, with 2 root causes. The root causes are provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

Comment: 1) Change in exports prevented by non-recomposable import 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.Behaviors.MefDelayedRegionCreationBehavior..ctor (Parameter="regionAdapterMappings", ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.RegionAdapterMappings")' on part 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.Behaviors.MefDelayedRegionCreationBehavior'.

Comment: 2) Change in exports prevented by non-recomposable import 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.Behaviors.MefAutoPopulateRegionBehavior..ctor (Parameter="regionViewRegistry", ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.IRegionViewRegistry")' on part 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Regions.Behaviors.MefAutoPopulateRegionBehavior'.

Comment: By default, imports do not allow recomposition (see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.importattribute.allowrecomposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). At least, you should allow it to rebuild your catalogs.

Comment: These Imports are in the Prism library though..

Comment: @Dennis, how to configure prism to allow recomposition ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that.
When the application starts the module catalog is built during for initialisation and thereafter it is not used anymore and even destroyed.
So dynamically, without restarting the application, adding modules is not possible with prism.